# My phone cannot detect GPS when running app

Tags: android, permissions, gps, location

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />    
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
```

i developed an app which sends a gps request. i tested my app on my tablet (android 4.3) and it works fine. but when i try on an android 5 or more, it keeps asking me to turn my gps on. here are the permissions that i used.

Comment: There is no `ACCESS_GPS` permission, so you can remove that. Beyond this, you will have better luck if you provide a [mcve] demonstrating what "sends a gps request" means, along with an explanation of what "it" is that "keeps asking [you] to turn [your] gps on".

Comment: @CommonsWare actually i wrote my codes in such a way that whenever location is detected as null, the app will open settings to go to the GPS section so that the user can switch it on. however, even after switching it on, it still ask me to switch it on